# Nesting LEFT JOIN statements

Tags: sql, sql-server, nested, left-join

Currently, these two LEFT JOINS return the max CaseloadID and ClientQuestionnaireDate respectively. I would like to be able to return the CaseloadID based upon the max ClientQuestionnaireDate so that it is returning the latest CaseloadID rather than simply the largest.

This should be possible by nesting the CaseloadID query inside the ClientQuestionnaireDate query but I am unsure how to do this.

```
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT ClientID, MAX(CaseloadID) [LastAssCase]
     FROM tblClientQuestionnaire
     WHERE QuestionnaireID = 10
     GROUP BY ClientID) AssessmentCaseload ON AssessmentCaseload.ClientID = c.ClientID
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT ClientID, MAX(ClientQuestionnaireDate) [LastAssDate]
     FROM tblClientQuestionnaire
     WHERE QuestionnaireID = 10
     GROUP BY ClientID) LastAssessment ON LastAssessment.ClientID = c.ClientID
```

Any help on how this can be accomplished would be greatly appreciated.

The relevant tables and columns are listed below:

- tblClientQuestionnaire - ClientID, ClientQuestionnaireDate, QuestionnaireID
- tblClientActivity - ClientID, ClientQuestionnaireDate
- tblCaseload - CaseloadID, CaseloadName

Comment: Kindly share sample data and desired output in formatted text (not images)

Comment: Nesting the JOINs is not the answer.   Think about a sub-query solution instead.

Comment: Why is tblCaseLoad relevant?  I dont see how it ties to the other two tables.  I would think an outer apply may work or a analytic row_number partitioned by client ID ordered by the clientquestionnairedate desc would make sense where row_number is 1.  I would need to see sample data expected results to figure more of this out.

Comment: If you want the caseloadID/Name relative to the questionnaire , You need to define how the tblClientquestionnaire relates to the tblCaseLoad.  ClientID is insufficient as we wouldn't know which questionnaire ties to which case thus knowing the max questionnaire date doesn't help us pick the right case.  So I suspect caseLoad has quesitonnaireID on it; but that's an assumption as it's not illustrated in your data structures.

Answer (score 0):

If we assume:

- tblCaseLoad has a clientID and questionniareID

However this seems odd because then a case is either repeated if it has multiple questionnaires.  If it's not repeated. then selecting the max questionnaire by client will give us the max case. since a case can only have 1 questionnaire.

We can:

- Use an outer apply Top1 to get the most recent questionnaire date for each client
- Use a left join to tblCaseLoad to get the case details relative to the most recent questionnaire date for each client

.

Maybe this but doubtful:

```
SELECT *
FROM tblClientActivity CA
OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 * 
             FROM tblClientQuestionnaire 
             WHERE CA.ClientID = CQ.ClientID 
               AND CA.ClientQuestionnaireDate = CA.ClientQuestionnaireDate
             ORDER BY CA.ClientQuestionnaireDate Desc) CQ2
LEFT JOIN tblCaseLoad CL
  on CQ2.Client = CL.ClientID
 and CQ2.QuestionnaireID = CL.QuestionnaireID
```

Or maybe this (more likely):

```
SELECT * 
FROM tblClientActivity CA
OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 * 
             FROM tblClientQuestionnaire 
             WHERE CA.ClientID = CQ.ClientID 
             ORDER BY ORDER BY ClientQuestionnaireDate DESC) CQ
LEFT JOIN tblCaseLoad
  on CQ.ClientID = CL.ClientID
 and CQ.QuestionnaireID = CL.QuestionnaireID
```

Both of these are guesses based on many assumptions as the information provided in the question lacks sufficient detail to both understand the problem and devise a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a window function. This assumes that CaseLoadID is also in tblClentActivity.

```
SELECT distinct tcq.ClientID, FirstValue(tca.CaseloadID) Over (Partition By tcq.ClientID Order by tcq.ClientQuestionnaireDate Desc)
FROM tblClientQuestionnaire tcq
INNER JOIN tblClentActivity tca on tca.ClientID = tcq.ClientID
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a Common Table Expression (CTE) for the LastAssessment query, instead of using a subquery. Something like this:

```
WITH LastAssessment as (
SELECT ClientID, 
    MAX(ClientQuestionnaireDate) [LastAssDate]
FROM tblClientQuestionnaire
WHERE QuestionnaireID = 10
GROUP BY ClientID
)
<... your query here ...>
LEFT JOIN (SELECT ClientID, CaseloadID [LastAssCase]                                               
        FROM tblClientQuestionnaire cq
        INNER JOIN LastAssessment la
            ON cq.ClientId = la.ClientId
            AND cq.ClientQuestionnaireDate = la.LastAssDate
        WHERE QuestionnaireID = 10
        GROUP BY ClientID ) AssessmentCaseload ON AssessmentCaseload.ClientID = c.ClientID
LEFT JOIN LastAssessment la
    ON la.ClientID = c.ClientID
```